# How to Exit with a record as result in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Delphi has an option to exit with a value (Example: Exit(0);), but how do I exit with a value if the return value is a record?

```
TIntResult = record
  Value: Integer;
  Error: String;
end;

function GetCount: TIntResult;
begin
  if not IsLoggedIn then
    Exit(Value: 0; Error: 'Not logged in'); // I want this

  if not IsAdmin then
    Exit(TIntResult(Value: 0; Error: 'Not Admin')); // or this
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, you can always use the `Result` variable and `Exit`.

But if you want to use the Delphi 2009+ `Exit(...)` syntax -- without giving it a `TIntResult`-typed variable --, the two most obvious options are these:

## Using a constructor

```pascal
type
  TIntResult = record
    Value: Integer;
    Error: string;
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer; const AError: string);
  end;

{ TIntResult }

constructor TIntResult.Create(AValue: Integer; const AError: string);
begin
  Value := AValue;
  Error := AError;
end;
```

Then you can do:

```pascal
function Test: TIntResult;
begin
  // ...
  Exit(TIntResult.Create(394, 'Invalid page.'));
end;
```

## Using a `TIntResult`-returning function

```pascal
function IntRes(AValue: Integer; const AError: string): TIntResult;
begin
  Result.Value := AValue;
  Result.Error := AError;
end;
```

Then you can do:

```pascal
function Test: TIntResult;
begin
  // ...
  Exit(IntRes(394, 'Invalid page.'));
end;
```

Comment: This easily shows how similar both variants are; one of the "oldschool" helper functions has been `Rect()` for ages.